Finding the integer part of a sum
I want to find the integer part of $$\sum_{n=1}^{10^9}\frac{1}{n^{2/3}}=S$$
I know there is a way using integration but I tried using a different approach.
I saw this approach with square roots but I extended it to cube roots.
My attempt is to make a telescoping series:
$${(n-1)^{2/3}}+(n)^{2/3}+(n(n-1))^{1/3}<{n^{2/3}+n^{2/3}+n^{2/3}}<{(n+1)^{2/3}+n^{2/3}+(n(n+1))^{1/3}}$$
$${3\sum_{n=1}^{10^9}\frac{(n)^{1/3}-(n-1)^{1/3}}{(n)-(n-1)}}>{S}>{3\sum_{n=1}^{10^9}\frac{(n+1)^{1/3}-(n)^{1/3}}{(n+1)-n}}$$
$$3000>S>2997$$ I got 2997 using binomial approximation. How can I make the inequality tighter using this method?
I am in High School, so please try to use maths at that level. Thanks.

It looks like the Rieman zeta function but with exponent $2/3$.

Hint: expand $(n+\tfrac12)^{1/3}-(n-\tfrac12)^{1/3}$ to see how well $3000-S$ is approximated by $\tfrac{3}{\sqrt[3]{2}}$.

@J.G. I got the answer 2997 using your method, but how can I proceed using my approach?

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Sum%5BDivide%5B1%2CPower%5Bn%2CDivide%5B2%2C3%5D%5D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2CPower%5B10%2C9%5D%7D%5D says $2997.55\dots$

@Lucenaposition I have verified it and solved using method mentioned by J.G. but how can I proceed using mine is my question?

The function $n^{2/3}$, with an exponent less than $1$, is everwhere concave downwards for positive $n$:
$2n^{2/3}>(n+a)^{2/3}+(n-a)^{2/3},0<a<n$
We also get from AM-GM:
$n^{2/3}>[(n+a)(n-a)]^{1/3},0<a<n$
Plug in $a=\frac12$and add these results. Since $(n+\frac12)-(n-\frac12)=1$, you can put this bound into your summation and the sum will telescope similarly to the sums in the original posting. You obtain
$S<3(\sqrt[3]{10^9+\frac12}-\sqrt[3]{\frac12})<2998,$
which pegs the integer part to $2997$.
Value of this upper bound to six digits: $2997.62$. Wolfram Alpha result given in comments: $2997.55$.

as 'a' tends to 0 I believe the approximation must get better? And what is 'OP'? @Oscar

OP is original posting. It is true that thecl approximation improves as $a\to0$, but I am not sure the telescoping mechanism works unless $a$ is taken as a multiple of $1/2$ to get a whole number difference between $n+a$ and $n-a$.
